# No debugging information found from gdb

Tags: gdb

I'm working on a single C file project. Here is the make command:

```
gcc -std=c99 -ggdb picaca.c -o aca -lm
```

It has segmentation fault. I used gdb to backtrace the segmentation, but it could not find debugging information:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000200419a77 in ?? ()
```

I double checked to have -g in gcc command, and set ulimit to unlimited. How do I fix this error?

Comment: An alternative interpretation of `??` is that you're at an invalid address due to, e.g, stack corruption.

What does `bt` say and what happens if you type `b main` - does it know where main is?

Comment: It looks like stack corruption. Try stepping through reasonable chunks of code to see where it happens, or for starters run your executable under valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have core files enabled? Try 'ulimit -c unlimited' on the command line if you don't see a core file in the execution directory.